# elaborate urls with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

i have a string that maybe contains text with links.
I use these instructions for elaborate it:

```
message = message.gsub(/http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]+/) do |m|      
      replace_url(m)
    end
```

if the string is `"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zToqLlM8ms&amp;playnext_from=TL&videos=qpCvM5Ocr3M&feature=sub"`
the instructions works.

but if the string is `"hi my video is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zToqLlM8ms&amp;playnext_from=TL&videos=qpCvM5Ocr3M&feature=sub"`
doesn't works

why?

how can i do?

thanks

Comment: Actually the pattern works, so maybe the problem is with replace_url. Try running with "***"(instead replace_url) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Beucase this not match a pattern. Get before url add expression to catch some crap before url.

You can also try match a regex pattern to every word. Because url is always one word separated word.

Comment: Your statement is not correct. Try this (in irb): `"hi my video is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zToqLlM8ms&amp;playnext_from=TL&videos=qpCvM5Ocr3M&feature=sub".gsub(/http[s]?:\/\/[^\s]+/, "!")`